# Redis - Creating Ad Stack and doing round robin for ad serving

Tags: redis

I have a Key, which has multiple data like

"KEY1" : { "V1" : "A1", "V2" : "A2", "V3" : "A3" }

I will code an HTTP API with the controller part fetching data from Redis

With each HTTP API request, I would fetch this data and do round robin, means first if you hit the GET API first time, I want to serve

V1, A1

Again you hit the GET API, then I want to serve

V2, A2

Note during this process more Values "V4" : "A4" and likewise can be added

What is the best way to do this ? I don't want to keep rotating the data also inside Redis for round robin as it would result in Read / Write.

Rather knowing the last played at which position is better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis `LIST` can easily do that with [RPOPLPUSH](https://redis.io/commands/rpoplpush) using the same key in source and destination.

No problem with adding more elements in run time. `RPUSH` for head of line, or `LPUSH` to the end.

**EDIT:**

Here's a Lua script example that cycle the list and count the times each element is returned.
Note1, you might want to add some checks to this script
Note2, the HASH does not need to exist prior to the call, and same goes for each element in the hash.
Note3, if the elements in the list are large, you might want to use some kind of digest in the hash field names to save some RAM

```
local ad = redis.call("RPOPLPUSH", KEYS[1], KEYS[1])
redis.call("HINCRBY", KEYS[2], ad, 1)
return ad
```

Comment: One question, what if I want to know the frequency of times the value was popped out in 100 RPOPLPUSH ? Note I might be adding more values so 100 does not mean that the first value would have popped out 100 times

Comment: @tahseen I'll edit my answer later when I get to a computer. The main idea is Lua script and hash key holding all ads in the list. When calling it it cycles the list and incr the hash element of the ad. The nice thing about it is that new adds inserted to the list do not need to be updated in the hash. The lua will handle it as incr treats non existing as 0